# Android Backup of ENTIRE SharedPreferences file

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, database-backups, android-backup-service

I have been trying to get the backup of my sharedpreferences file in my Android app working and so far it is not. I am using the simple Google code from the developer's guide. Below is the code for the `MyPrefsBackup` class.

```
public class MyPrefsBackup extends BackupAgentHelper {

    // The name of the SharedPreferences file

    static final String PREFS = "UserDB";

    // A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data

    static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "prefs";

    // Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent

  public  void onCreate() {

        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
        addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);


    }
```

I think I have finally realized that the `PREFS_BACKUP_KEY` actually has to be the specific key that I stored the data under.  I was just using "prefs" so I think that's why no data was being backed up.  However, I am storing quite a bit of data in the `SharedPreferences` file so how can I go ahead and save the entire `SharedPreferences` files without specifiying every individual key.  (some keys are generated by the app so I don't even know if they are in use until the user inputs their data).

I want to know is there a way to just tell the `BackupHelper` class to backup the entire `SharedPreferences` file?

Answer (score 1):

The key you pass to `addHelper` *isn't* the key you use inside your `SharedPreferences`. It's a key that identifies this particular helper from all the helpers you add. The `SharedPreferencesBackupHelper` backs up every value in each `SharedPreferences` file you tell it about.

If your `SharedPreferences` aren't being backed up, it's for a different reason. Check that the name of the SharedPreferences file is correct, and that you've specified your key correctly in the `<meta-data>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml .

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. This is my code link http://pastebin.com/Y3Jismaq. Is anything wrong in my code or is there any different mechanism for testing before publishing the app.

Comment: @AndroidDev If you have a new question, you know what to do. But I'm sure you already know that "Is anything wrong in my code" isn't really a question for this site.

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually i want to know that how we can test the app after implementing backup feature before publishing in the app store.

Answer (score 1):

Getting sharedpreference files backup was easy one. Please find the below example to understand much better:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("EmpDetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
prefEditor.putString("empName1", "valuelabs");
prefEditor.putString("empName2", "webmd");
prefEditor.commit();
```

So If you want to retrive backup for shared preference files, You need to use the below logic. Here you can access based on your key if the values are required.

```
public class MyPrefsBackup extends BackupAgentHelper {

    // The name of the SharedPreferences file
    static final String PREFS = "EmpDetails";
   // A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data
    static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "PREF";

  public  void onCreate() {

        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
        addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("Test", getApplicationContext().MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)
```

Date For the Backup Folder

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMMM_yyyy HH_mm_ss");
            String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Export SharedPreferences

```
exportSH("Test.xml", strDate);
```

Exporting the SharedPreferences .xml File in a Folder to the Downloads directory

```
private void exportSH(String sh_name, String strDate){




        File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + 
                File.separator + "Backup Folder "+strDate+ 
                File.separator );

          boolean success = true;
           if (!sd.exists()) {
               success = sd.mkdir();
           }
           if (success) {

        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
       FileChannel source=null;
       FileChannel destination=null;
       String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ context.getPackageName() +"/shared_prefs/"+ sh_name;
       String backupDBPath = sh_name;
       File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
       File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
       try {
            source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
            source.close();
            destination.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
           }}
```

You can import the Files with small changes. Some people said that it won't work so easily but it does. Just make sure you create a empty Sharedpreferences File before you import, because otherwise it doesn't work.

You can do this for example

```
    SharedPreferences dummy = getSharedPreferences("dummy", getApplicationContext().MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
                Editor editor = dummy.edit();
editor.putBoolean("asdf", true);

    editor.commit();
```

And if you import it on the same Layout where the SharedPreferences are used, you can use this to refresh

```
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a challenge for me to figure out, but I got it. Hopeful it'll be useful to someone. ~Ann :-)

ORY's answer will work, but you will need to exit the app completely in order for the new setting to load. This is an update of his method and a way to import the Sharepreference. Toasting will not show when restarting through this method. **Remember you will need to create a .xml file if none existed. This method used "transferFrom". You will also need to override the backpressed() to clear the activity as this will create layers of activities.

To execute:

importSH("App_settings.xml", "/TodoFolder/Backup/");

Method:

```
    private void importSH(String sh_name, String location){


          File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                  getAbsolutePath() +location);


         File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
         FileChannel source=null;
         FileChannel destination=null;
         String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ ToDoListActivity.this.getPackageName() +"/shared_prefs/"+ sh_name;
         String backupDBPath = sh_name;
         File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
         File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);



             try {
                  source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                  destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();

                  destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                  source.close();
                  destination.close();

 // Toast.makeText(this, "App need to exit to load new setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //will not show when rebooting. Not sure how to fix it.

                  String value =shared.getString("Demo List",null);
                     if (value != null) {

                         shared.edit().remove("Demo List").commit(); //remove the item created by dummy SharedPreferences, as mention. 
                     } 

 //restartin app to original activity.
                     Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(ToDoListActivity.this, ToDoListActivity.class);
                       int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
                       PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ToDoListActivity.this, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                       AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                       mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
                       System.exit(0);

              } catch(IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

           }
```