# How to refresh SharedPreferences after adding an xml file to its storage location

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have the following problem: Since I want to keep my shared preference data even if the .apk is uninstalled I copy its .xml file to an external location as described here: [Android Backup of ENTIRE SharedPreferences file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991355/android-backup-of-entire-sharedpreferences-file). However, after reinstalling the app and starting the application I import the .xml to the shared preferences location but it won't be found by the app at the very first time. It works after shutting the app down and restarting it again. What can I do that it already works from the beginning? It seems like to be necessary to refresh the shared preferences directory, but how can that be done within the app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are lucky that you only have to restart the app. On many devices/systems you have to reboot the device first.

Answer (score 0):

You can put files in a directory derived from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). These files will persist after an uninstall. However, a user can delete those files any time they like, regardless of whether your app is installed or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes, this is what I did. But after the reinstall, I want to fetch this data again. Therefore, I copy it from the external location to my shared preferences location within the app again. But when trying to access the file via shared preferences afterwards, it won't be found. So I have to restart the app for that.